# Having trouble solving clojure.string/replace "is not a function" error

Tags: replace, clojurescript

Here is the original code block for ClojureScript's string "replace" function:

```
(defn replace
  "Replaces all instance of match with replacement in s.
  match/replacement can be:
  string / string
  pattern / (string or function of match)."
 [s match replacement]
 (cond
   (string? match)
   (.replace s (js/RegExp. (gstring/regExpEscape match) "g") replacement)

   (instance? js/RegExp match)
   (if (string? replacement)
     (replace-all s match replacement)
     (replace-all s match (replace-with replacement)))

   :else (throw (str "Invalid match arg: " match))))
```

As you can see on this line:`[s match replacement]`, this method accepts three arguments.

From my REPL:

```
user=> (replace ":c41120" ":" "")

ArityException Wrong number of args (3) passed to: core/replace  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)
```

Am I the only one who thinks I have passed the correct number of arguments (3)? Any idea why this is failing?

**Question, Part II: Getting Specific**

In my components.cljs file, I have these 'requires':

```
(ns labrador.components
(:require [re-frame.core :as rf]
          [reagent.core :refer [atom]]
          [clojure.string :as s]
          [labrador.helpers :as h]))
```

I've had success using "s/join" and "s/blank?" in this file. But when I try using "s/replace" like below (note that the "replace" call is on line 484):

```
            (for [roll-count order-item-roll-counts]
              (let [key (key roll-count)
                    val (val roll-count)
                    code (s/replace key ":" "")]
```

...I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: s.replace is not a function
  at clojure$string$replace (string.cljs?rel=1489020198332:48)
  at components.cljs?rel=1489505254528:484
```

...And when I explicitly call the replace function, like so:

```
code (clojure.string/replace key ":" "")]
```

...I still get the exact same error, as if I'm still calling "s/replace."

I'm new to Clojure/ClojureScript, so bare with my apparent ignorance.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, it looks like you're running in a Clojure REPL, not a ClojureScript one, secondly, you're calling [clojure.core/replace](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/replace), instead of [clojure.string/replace](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/replace).

Comment: Yes, clojure.string/replace works in my REPL, and I've used it successfully in my ClojureScript. Thanks for clarifying that distinction. But I'm getting errors when I try this one particular replace function. I'll update my question with more details.

Answer (score 5):

I found the error. I was trying to do a replace on a key, not a string. Once I converted the key to a string before calling the replace function, by changing `(s/replace key ":" "")` with `(s/replace (str key) ":" "")`, all was well.

I was thrown way off-course by the ambiguous error message. Being told the function 'replace' isn't a function when it clearly is, rather than being told the function can't perform it's job because the data passed isn't a string, just cost me about three hours of dev time.

Comment: If you're trying to get a string from a keyword without the leading :, you can use the `name` function.

Comment: To clarify, error is not indicating that `clojure.string/replace` is not a function. Instead it is a result of a failing `(.replace s ...)` call in the implementation. Compare `(let [s ":abc"] (.replace s ":" ""))` with `(let [s :abc] (.replace s ":" ""))`. The latter reproduces the error and is essentially indicating that there is no `replace` function defined on keywords.

Answer (score 2):

I came to this issue when the first args is a number, not a string.

I think the error message is kinds of misleading

Comment: Thanks! Solved my case